# Inserting videos to existing image slider using viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on an android app that uses viewpager to create a slider from images loaded from URL. It is working fine.

But now I need to improve it adding not only images, but also videos from URL also.

This my code for the current viewpager:

In fragment:

```
  final String url_postmedia = "https://...postsmedia/";


        String mediapostfile []= mediafile.split(",");

        String mediaposttype []= mediatype.split(",");

        urls = new String[mediapostfile.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mediapostfile.length; i++) {

            if (mediaposttype[i].equals("1")){
               urls[i] = url_postmedia+mediapostfile[i];
            }

        }




        holder.mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(context,urls));


        holder.indicator.setViewPager(holder.mPager);



//Set circle indicator radius


        NUM_PAGES = urls.length;

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                holder.mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 3000, 3000);

        // Pager listener over indicator
        holder.indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

            }
        });
```

And the adapter:

```
public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private String[] urls;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, String[] urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urls = urls;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.length;
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        imageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //this will log the page number that was click


            }
        });


        Glide.with(context)
                .load(urls[position])
                .into(imageView);

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }


}
```

From the server I receive two String arrays: `mediapostfile[]` which contains the file names, and `mediaposttype[]` which contains the file types, "1" for images and "2" for videos.

What should I take into account to use my current code to add videos to the slider?